# Is possible to make a circular Pane in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, pane

I want to make a circular Pane (AnchorPane) instead of a "traditional" square.
Anyone know how I can do that ?

JavaFX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's already an implementation of a `CircularPane`on the [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org/) project.

Have a look at this [link](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras/blob/8.0/jfxtras-common/src/main/java/jfxtras/scene/layout/CircularPane.java) for the code.

Download the [samples](http://jfxtras.org/resources/java/jfxtras-labs-samples-8.0-r4-SNAPSHOT-shadow.jar) jar to test it:

[image: circular pane]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. I have a lot to learn from that code :)