# JavaFX clock number transitions

Tags: java, javafx, rotation, javafx-2, transformation

I am attempting to create a clock in JavaFX, everything worked out well, except for the numbers which represent the time (from 1 to 12).
I have this piece of code:

```
    Group numbers = new Group();
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        //create a label.
        Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(i));
        //center it
        label.setTranslateX(100);
        label.setTranslateY(100);
        label.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(i * (360 / 12)));
        //rotate it.
        numbers.getChildren().add(label);
    }
```

This doesn't work, the numbers are just rotated in the center, but i want them to move outside (to the edge of the outer circle, like a normal clock.
Can someone help me?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you combine `Translate` with `Rotate` transforms:

```
Group numbers = new Group();
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    //create a label.
    Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(i==0?12:i));
    label.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(i * (360d / 12d)));
    label.getTransforms().add(new Translate(100d,100d));

    numbers.getChildren().add(label);
}
```

You will have a 'rotated' clock:

[image: Clock 1]

But as you can see, you are rotating your labels, not their position.

One way to approach this is finding the position of each label by using a small `Circle`, rotating it to its final position and then moving the label:

```
Group numbers = new Group();
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    //create a label.
    Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(i==0?12:i));
    Circle c=new Circle(1);

    c.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(i * (360d / 12d)));
    c.getTransforms().add(new Translate(0,-100));

    label.setTranslateX(c.localToParent(0,0).getX());
    label.setTranslateY(c.localToParent(0,0).getY());

    numbers.getChildren().addAll(c,label);
}
```

[image: Clock 2]

Note I've adjusted the translation to start right at the 12 hour position.

You will notice the labels are located down and right from their circle, so you should move them accordingly.

**EDIT**

To avoid the need of fixing the labels position, you can use a `StackPane` to wrap each pair of circles and labels:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(i==0?12:i));
    Circle c=new Circle(1);

    c.getTransforms().add(new Rotate((i) * (360d / 12d)));
    c.getTransforms().add(new Translate(0,-100d));
    label.setTranslateX(c.localToParent(0,0).getX());
    label.setTranslateY(c.localToParent(0,0).getY());

    StackPane sp = new StackPane(c,label);
    numbers.getChildren().add(sp);
}
```

[image: Clock 3]

Finally, have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181436/is-possible-to-make-a-circular-pane-in-javafx), maybe it's easier just using a circular pane.